# Modular wall system that uses the same grid as dropped ceiling

Tags: walls, ceiling, acoustic, ceiling-tiles

I want to build a space with easily-reconfigurable acoustics. The best idea I had so far is to have a modular system similar to a dropped ceiling w/ suspension grids: the material with desired acoustic properties is made into or gets coupled with standard 2x2ft (or 595x595mm if in Europe) panels and then inserted into the grid. The solutions dropped ceiling are ubiquitous around the world, but there seems to be nothing like that for the walls.

Does anybody know if there is a product or a solution that would allow me to have a grid with the same 2x2ft or 600x600mm dimensions, but mounted vertically on a wall? Ideally I want a solution that would allow me to have the exact same panels on the walls and the ceiling

Comment: Welcome. This is essentially a shopping question and therefore off topic here. Please see the [help].

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this done in reconfigurable recording spaces before. It was all custom. The wall panels were hung with low profile French cleats. You should likely be working with your acoustical consultant to determine what parameters they need for the panels, then either locating a manufacturer to build to those specs, or designing your own panels for custom build. I'm not aware of any brand-agnostic system to do what you describe, and brand-specific shopping questions are off topic for this SE.